# set bash alias from bash script (not command line)

Tags: bash, alias

Differently from bash shell (for create new alias):

```
alias test="echo test"
```

if I do the same thing using a bash script, alias does not run:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias test="echo test"
```

also export it, same problem:

```
alias test="echo test" ; export test
```

maybe correct: really "test" in not a variable. So, how put any aliases to bash script and let them available in my environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197461/how-to-set-an-alias-inside-a-bash-shell-script).

**helloworld.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
alias helloworld="echo helloworld"
```

Executing the script as follows:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ . helloworld.bash
```

and `[vagrant@localhost ~]$ helloworld` results in:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ helloworld
helloworld
```

Answer (score 1):

`alias` is not available in a non interactive shell. Use `bash`'s option `-i`. If the `-i` option is present, the shell is interactive.

```
#!/bin/bash -i
alias test="echo test"
test
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: `-bash: test: command not found`

Comment: @utrecht: You're doing something wrong. `test` is a shell builtin.